# Reference resourceDictionary from parent .xaml file

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm learning WPF. I'm trying to reference `ResourceDictionary` in `App.xaml` from `AboutView.xaml` to apply the `materialview` style.

Tried pack `uri` way and also `"../"` but VSS is still complaining `"An error occurred while trying to find App.xaml"`.

The folder structure:

What am I doing wrong?

**AboutView.xaml**
[image: AboutView.xaml]

**App.xaml**
[image: App.xaml]

**To ASh:**

So with referenced, my materialview button shows nicely.

[image: Button is indigo in color]

Relying on App.xaml to apply materialview style across all Windows doesn't work if I don't reference it explicitly. The button is stripped of its style.

[image: Dull gray button w/o style]

Comment: app.xaml is usually not a ResourceDictionary, but contains an Application. I'd suggest to move the resources from the app.xaml into a separate ResourceDictionary and reference that from your view.

Comment: Hey Lennart, that worked! If you can replicate your comment as an answer, I'll mark yours as official. Thanks so much.

Comment: @f0rfun, resources, declared in App.xaml are available from Windows xaml without loading any merged dictionaries. "move the resources from the app.xaml into a separate ResourceDictionary and reference that from your view" is unnecessary work

Comment: @ASh, insightful! But if I didn't reference it, the styles are being applied in the designer view but during runtime/debug mode, the styles are missing which caused me to think my referencing was the problem. Would you know why my resources declared are not applied to my Windows xaml?

Comment: @f0rfun, very strange. which styles (or rather resources) are missing?

Comment: @ASh, I updated the question with pictures showing with and without referencing of App.xaml on a simple button. Curious to know why too! So much learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app.xaml isn't a ResourceDictionary, but contains the definition for your Application (it starts with an `<Application>`element, not a `<ResourceDictionary>`). You can move your resources out of the app.xaml into their own ResourceDictionary and then reference that dictionary from your view and other elements as needed.